# using a text field and an if else statement on a wordpress page, send users to an outside website

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am the webmaster for a non-profit.  one of our volunteers would like me to create a webpage that will be accessable from a QR code.  The webpage would ask for the visitor's zipcode, or city or county and would then go to the correct outside website.

Our website is based through BlueHost and runs through WordPress.

I know this can be done in html but I am not sure how to do it in WordPress.

I have started to create the code in html format but the function code is not working.  I am only working with the zipcode portion right now but also need help with the other selections and then turning it into a WordPress webpage.

here is the current code I have written

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Find your nearest Meeting </title>
</head>
<body>
<h1><b>Finding your nearest meeting</b></h1>
<p>When leaving your treatment center and going back home, it is importaint to find your nearest AA meeting as soon as possible.<br>
The Area 26 Treatment Committee wants to make this easy for you.  
Please type in your zipcode <b><i>OR</i></b> your city <b><i>OR</i></b> your county in <i><u>one</u></i> of the boxes below.<br>
You will then be directed to the Intergroup meeting webpage that serves that area. 
Here you will be able to locate a meeting and continue your journey in sobrity.<br>
Remeber, <i>We shall be with you in the Fellowship of the Spirit, and you will surely meet some of us as you trudge the
Road of Happy Destiny.</i>
</p>
<br>
<label for="Zipcode">Zipcode:</label>
<input type="text" id="Zipcode" name="Zipcode">
<p id="Zipcode"></p>
<br><br><br>
<label for="City">City:</label>
<input type="text" id="City" name="City">
<p id="City"></p>
<br><br><br>
<label for="County"> County:</label>
<input type="text" id="County" name="County">
<p id="County"></p>
<br><br><br>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Check</button>
<script>
function myFunction()
{
var a=document.getElementById("Zipcode").value;
if(a=="40342") {
document.getElementById("Zipcode").innerHTML="Thank you. You will be directed to the Bluegrass Intergroup’s Meeting page"; 
<a href="https://www.bluegrassintergroup.org/meetings/"> Bluegrass Intergroup Meeting Page</a>;
window.open(https://www.bluegrassintergroup.org/meetings/, ‘newwindow’)
}
else if(a=="40358")
{
document.getElementById("Zipcode").innerHTML="Thank you. You will be directed to the Bluegrass Intergroup’s Meeting page"; 
<a href="https://www.bluegrassintergroup.org/meetings/"> Bluegrass Intergroup Meeting Page</a>;
window.open(https://www.bluegrassintergroup.org/meetings/, ‘newwindow’)
}
else
{
document.getElementById("Zipcode").innerHTML="I'm sorry but we have not found an Intergroup Meeting Page that has meetings in that area. Please go to the Area 26 meeting page for a list of meetings in Kentucky, Southern Indiana and Ohio.";
<a href="https://www.area26.net/wp/?post_type=tsml_meeting"> Area 26 Find A Meeting Page</a>;
window.open(https://www.area26.net/wp/?post_type=tsml_meeting, ‘newwindow’)
```

Comment: You might consider using a store locator plugin for WordPress  rather than trying to do this programming task yourself. For example https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-store-locator/

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Wordpress page and insert the contact form (contactform7 plugin) into it. And insert the zip selection javascript code into the contact form.I am also a developer of the non- profi organization. If you do not understand how to implement write me - I will help.

Comment: I can see how this form will help with the text boxes.  However, I need to be able to use the information in the text boxes to send them to an outside webpage.   The contactform7 seems to only be able to send email and not direct them to an outside webpage. Is there a way to set it up so that it will send the visitor to a specific webpage depending on the information in the text box?